# jquery removing all appended elements

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to code a todo list form. this form can contain unlimited rows. the rows each contain a text input field with 2 buttons beside it. 1 of the buttons adds a new row below, the second button deletes the row.

The problem is, when I click the add button a bunch of times, it removes ALL of the elements that were added below it when i click on the delete icon for that row.

I hope im making sense, maybe the code will explain whats going on.

Heres the PHP code for the todo-list form page:

```
<div class="table table-todo">

    <?php include 'projects-add-task.php'; ?>

</div>
```

Here is the contents of `projects-add-task.php`:

```
<div class="field">
<input type="text" name="task[]" />
<a href="#" title="Add Task Below" class="todo-add"><img src="images/icon-todo-add.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='images/icon-todo-add-h.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icon-todo-add.png'" /></a>
<?php if ($_GET['show_delete'] == 'yes') { ?>
<a href="#" title="Delete This Task" class="todo-delete"><img src="images/icon-todo-delete.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='images/icon-todo-delete-h.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icon-todo-delete.png'" /></a>
<?php } ?>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery that isnt working 100% correctly:

```
$('.todo-add').live('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $parent = $(this).parent('.field');     
    $.get('projects-add-task.php?show_delete=yes', function (data) { $parent.append(data); }, 'html');
});

$('.todo-delete').live('click', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.field').remove();
});
```

I had to use `live` for the `.todo-add` icon because it was not working obviously for the newly appended rows. however im unsure if this is necessary for the `.todo-delete` icon, but i did it just to be sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `after` and not `append`:

```
function (data) { $parent.append(data); }
```

should be

```
function (data) { $parent.after(data); }
```

Also, `live` is actually deprecated now. You should be using `on`.

Comment: tried using `on`, doesn't work. `live` works fine, and the `after` function worked a charm.

Comment: Probably you're using an older version of jQuery, anyway you got what you need:)

Answer (score 0):

you are adding many divs with the class "field" and then asking jquery to delete them on the delete button.

you need to either have unique ID for each row and then delete that ID element os simply work witht he parent of the delete button, no need to specify the '.field' in the parent()

```
$('.todo-delete').live('click', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: no i do not need a unique id, using the `parent` function finds the parent element of the clicked element and removes it accordingly. the problem was i was using `append` rather than `after` as mentioned above.